# Get new position of Layout after animation ends

Tags: android, translate-animation

Small question, in android after you use the TranslateAnimation how do you get the position it has taken.

In my app when the user touches an image it will move up and show a input screen.
But when the image reaches its final position i want to stick the image to its new location.
But when i use getHeight or getLayoutParams i always get the old position.

```
public void moveProducts() {
    float addAmmountY = -250;
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,addAmmountY); //(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
    anim.setDuration(1000);

final LinearLayout product_buttons = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.product_buttons);

anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //TODO set new location of the linearlayout
    }
});


product_buttons.startAnimation(anim);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   product_buttons.requestLayout();
}
```

After the animation try to get the new position of the image.